# php, how to convert any number to float without removing fractional zero

Tags: php

When i convert number like 15.26 to float (i know it is already in float) it return 15.26 using below method

```
$float = (float) 15.26; //15.26 (data type float)
```

and it work perfect

but when i convert 15 to float it return only 15

```
$float = (float) 15; //15 (data type float)
```

instead of only 15 how to get "15.0" or "15.00" with float data type

Comment: use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: but number_format return string data type

Comment: use `floatval($float)`, The precision never fixed in float number, You can set `ini_set('float', 2)`

Comment: i was tried floatval($folat) but it return :float 15

Comment: There's no difference in the ***numeric value***; `15 == 15.0 == 15.00000`. When you do `(float)15` you get a float, whether it sports a decimal point or not. If you want to *format your number for output*, use `number_format`!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `number_format` function like this:

```
echo number_format(15,2);
                // ^^ Your value and number of digits after fraction point
```

Read : [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Demo : https://3v4l.org/bY5Wo

Comment: The OP needs float number not string.

Comment: see this `$float = number_format(15,2); var_dump($float);`

Comment: but number_format return string data type how to get this with float data type

Comment: - If you are comparing, then it doesn't matter if you're using 15 or 15.0 or 15.00

- If you are printing, it doesn't matter if its a string or float.

I accept this answer. Why do you need it to be float?